# Python3.5 to python3.7 upgrade in the build

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

Idea is to build the distroless docker image and available python3 google distorless image version is 3.7 - gcr.io/distroless/python3. Our code is already compiled and running with python3.5 version and required to upgrade the version into 3.7 so that we can get rid of the library, compactability issues and can make use of the distroless image with verison 3.7.  Some questions are,

1. Will version upgrade cause any issues to the existing code compilation?
2. Do we need to change all the requirements.txt versions according to the 3.7?
3. If yes, will there is an impact of the application?

Answer (score 0):

the Python language does not provide backward compatibility. My recommendation for you is to run your code on a virtual env with the new version of Python and test your code. If you do not want to use virtual env you could create a new docker image with the Python version and test your app. Regarding the requirements.txt, without seeing the libraries or packages there, it is impossible to say if you should change the file.